# Apex : Escape character issue in json deserialization

Tags: apex, string

I have an api response which is been parsed to a map using JSON.deserializeUntyped function. In the response , i have a key value pair as:
`'{"primaryuser": "test\\test"}'`

When i try to fetch it from the map , i need the backslash character. But below string is obtained :

```
test\test.
```

Now since backslash character is escaped , when i try to find backslash character , it doesn't showup.

Please find below code for reproducing this issue :

```
String str = '{"primaryuser": "test\\test"}'; 
Map<String,Object> maps= (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
System.debug('str '+str);
System.debug('value '+maps.get('primaryuser'));
```

Below is the debug log which i'am getting :

```
18:42:44.27 (29338484)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|value test  est
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On deserialization, you are successfully escaping the backslash, which makes the deserialized string `'test\test'`

`\t` is the escape sequence for a tab, which is exactly what you're seeing in your example output (`'test\test'` ==> `'test    est'`).

To solve this problem, you need more backslashes (a total of 4, to be precise).

`'test\\\\test'` is deserialized to `'test\\test'`, which when printed will appear as `'test\test'`.

Alternatively, replacing backslashes for a forward slash would also work. Using your example code:

```
String str = '{"primaryuser": "test\\test"}';
str = str.replace('\\', '\\\\'); //str.replace('\\', '/'); // replacing with a forward slash would also work
Map<String,Object> maps= (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
System.debug('str '+str);
System.debug('value '+maps.get('primaryuser'));
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, is there any other way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the issue, but if you are pulling in the value from elsewhere you may need to do a quick replace to get to this

```
String str = '{"primaryuser": "test\\/test"}';
```

Comment: str is actually coming from rest API.

Comment: parse and replace the return string before deserializing it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that would be my last option.

Comment: Then get the person providing the feed to change it on their side